# Writing a generic function to get common variable from multiple enums in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, generics, enums

I want to write a generic method which can access multiple enum's cases as well as their common variables.

```
    enum MyEnum:String,CaseIterable {
        case a = "a"

        var ourVar:MyAnotherEnum {
            switch self {
            case .a:
                return MyAnotherEnum.a1
            }
        }
    }

    enum MyAnotherEnum:String,CaseIterable {
        case a1 = "a1"
    }


    enum YourEnum:String,CaseIterable {
        case b = "b"

        var ourVar:YourAnotherEnum {
            switch self {
            case .b:
                return YourAnotherEnum.b1
            }
        }
    }

    enum YourAnotherEnum:String,CaseIterable {
        case b1 = "b1"
    }
```

My and Your enums both having "ourVar" as common. Now, I want to write a method that can print all the values if I pass an enum. Something like this:

```
printAll(MyEnum.self) //Should print "a" and "a1"
```

I tried like iterating an enum like:

```
    func printAll<T>(_ id:T.Type) where T:RawRepresentable, T:CaseIterable {
        for c in T.allCases {
            print(c.rawValue) //Prints the value correctly
            print(c.ourVar) //Throws error "Value of type 'T' has no member 'ourVar'"
        }
    }
```

My exact expectation is, `printAll(myEnum)` should print the "a" and "a1".

My code flow is complex to explain but I definitely need this method to save thousand of lines. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: So you want `printAll` to only accept inputs that have `ourVar` defined on them? Or do you want it to accepts all enums conforming to `CaseIterable`?

Comment: Is `ourVar` of different types?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want printAll that accept enums with ourVar alone

Comment: @PGDev No.. They all are same type only (returns String)

Comment: But in your code `ourVar` is of type `MyAnotherEnum` and `YourAnotherEnum`. I've added an answer as per your code. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a `CommonEnum` `protocol` with `ourVar` as one of the requirements like so,

```
protocol CommonEnum {
    associatedtype T
    var ourVar: T { get }
}
```

Now conform the above `protocol` to `MyEnum` and `YourEnum`,

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable, CommonEnum {
    //....
}


enum YourEnum: String,CaseIterable, CommonEnum {
    //....
}
```

Next, the `printAll(_:)` method will be

```
func printAll<T>(_ id: T.Type) where T: CommonEnum & RawRepresentable & CaseIterable {
    for c in T.allCases {
        print(c.rawValue)
        print(c.ourVar)
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
printAll(MyEnum.self) //prints a and a1
```